# iTunesConnect. Invited External Testers do not receive emails with invitation

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

For one of my projects I added 2 external testers as it is on the image below:

[image]

But they didn't receive an emails from Apple. What should I do more? I need to use external testers because I know that **External Tester** (*opposite to Internal Tester*) do not have an access to every app on my account, except that one he was invited to.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to your app -> prerelease in itunes connect
- External testers -> Add

They will be able to download only the binary that they are allowed to....

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes turning testing off and on again re-sends email to everybody. I also noticed that TestFlight doesn't always send emails or push notifications when a new build is released

Answer (score 0):

**External testers do not receive emails immediately once I add them to the list**.

> Your app must pass Beta App Review **before** you can invite your external testers to test it.

[image]

> As soon as it is approved, you can send the external testers an update email by clicking Send Invites from the External Testers column on Builds

[image]

*Source: [TestFlight Beta Testing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH35-SW2)*